# Is there way to remove merged branches in submodules

Tags: git

I use this **alias** in .gitconfig

`[alias] sweep = "!git branch --merged | grep  -v '\\*\\|master\\|develop' | xargs -n 1 git branch -d "`

to remove merged branches, but its not working for submodules.
So is there anyone have idea to make this git command working on submodules also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`git submodule foreach <command>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#Documentation/git-submodule.txt-foreach--recursiveltcommandgt) to run a command in all submodules. As you already have your `sweep` alias, you should be able to just run:

```
git submodule foreach git sweep
```

Which will then change into each submodule directory and run the `git sweep` alias.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem.